# The rounded box that wanted to be an arc

Tags: c++, object-oriented, inheritance, fltk

This is from Bjarne Stroustrup's *C++ Programming: Principles and Practice*, Chapter 13 Exercise 2:

> Draw a box with rounded corners. Define a class `Box`, consisting of four lines and four arcs.

I've already defined `class Arc` and using existing facilities (`class Lines`) for drawing the lines.

Here is the code that draws a rounded box of random size:

**roundedBox.h**

```
//#include "GUI.h"
//#include "Simple_window.h"
//#include <iostream>

namespace Graph_lib{
// Class Arc
bool validInput(int w, int h);

class Arc: public Ellipse{
public:
  Arc(Point p, int w, int h, double s, double e)
  : Ellipse(Point(p.x, p.y), w, h), start(s), end(e) 
  { if (!validInput(w,h)) error("Invalid input Arc"); }

  void draw_lines() const;
  // starting and ending angle of the arc: start from 3'oclock counterclockwise
  double start;
  double end;
};

// Member function
void Arc::draw_lines() const{
    if(color().visibility()) fl_arc(point(0).x, point(0).y, major() , minor() , start, end);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Class RoundedBox
class Box: public Lines{
public:
    Box(Point p, int w, int h);
    Box(Point ul, Point dr);

private:
    Point upperLeft;
    Point downRight;

    int width;
    int height; 
    // 1/4th of width and height, respectively 
    int roundWidth;
    int roundHeight;
};
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Function Implementation
// Helper function
bool validInput(int w, int h){
    if (w < 0 || h < 0) return false;
    else return true;
}

bool validInput(Point ul, Point dr){
    if(ul.x - dr.x < 0 || ul.y - dr.y < 0) return false;
    return true;
}

// Class Constructors
Box::Box(Point p, int w, int h)
    : upperLeft(p), downRight(p.x + w, p.y + h), roundWidth(w / 4), roundHeight(h / 4) 
{ 
    if (!validInput(w,h)) error("Invalid input Box");
    Lines::add(Point(p.x + roundWidth, p.y), Point(p.x + w - roundWidth, p.y));
    Lines::add(Point(p.x + w, p.y + roundHeight), Point(p.x + w, p.y + h - roundHeight));
    Lines::add(Point(p.x + w - roundWidth, p.y + h), Point(p.x + roundWidth, p.y + h));
    Lines::add(Point(p.x, p.y + h - roundHeight), Point(p.x, p.y + roundHeight));
}

Box::Box(Point ul,Point dr) 
    : upperLeft(ul), downRight(dr), roundWidth((dr.x - ul.x) / 10.), roundHeight((dr.y - ul.y) / 10.) 
{ 
    if(!validInput(ul, dr)) error ("Invalid input Box");
    Lines::add(Point(ul.x + roundWidth, ul.y), Point(dr.x - roundWidth, ul.y));
    Lines::add(Point(dr.x, ul.y + roundHeight), Point(dr.x, dr.y - roundHeight));
    Lines::add(Point(dr.x - roundWidth, dr.y), Point(ul.x + roundWidth, dr.y));
    Lines::add(Point(ul.x, dr.y - roundHeight), Point(ul.x, ul.y + roundHeight));
}

} // end of Graph_lib namespace
```

**roundedBox.cpp**

```
#include "GUI.h"
#include "Simple_window.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "roundedBox.h"
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(){
 // window parameters
 int winWidth = 800;
 int winHeight = 600;
 Point center((x_max() - winWidth) / 2., (y_max() - winHeight) / 2.);
 Simple_window* sw = new Simple_window(center, winWidth, winHeight, "Chapter 13 Exercise 2");

 // rounded box parameters
 int width = 500;
 int height = 400;
 int xCoord = (sw->x_max() - width) / 2;
 int yCoord = (sw->y_max() - height) / 2;

try{
    // draw the 4 conrer arcs clockwise, starting from the top left corner
    // each center of an arc is shiftet away from the center of the rounded box by multiples of its width and height
    Graph_lib::Arc ulArc(Point(xCoord + width/2, yCoord + height/2), width/2, height/2, 90, 180); 
    ulArc.draw_lines();
    sw->attach(ulArc);
    Graph_lib::Arc urArc(Point(xCoord + width, yCoord + height/2), width/2, height/2, 0, 90); 
    urArc.draw_lines();
    sw->attach(urArc);
    Graph_lib::Arc drArc(Point(xCoord + width, yCoord + height), width/2, height/2, 270, 0); 
    drArc.draw_lines();
    sw->attach(drArc);
    Graph_lib::Arc dlArc(Point(xCoord + width/2, yCoord + height), width/2, height/2, 180, 270); 
    dlArc.draw_lines();
    sw->attach(dlArc);

    // create a box with rounded corners by creating four non-intersecting lines that will match the arcs
    // both arcs and roundedbox are parametrized in function of the width and height 
    Graph_lib::Box rb(Point(xCoord, yCoord), width, height);
    sw->attach(rb);

    sw->wait_for_button();
    delete sw;
}catch(exception& e){
    cerr << e.what() << endl;
    getchar();
}catch(...){
    cerr <<"Default exception!"<< endl;
    getchar();
}
return 0;
}
```

### Output:

[image]

### Suggestion:

Could I alter the definition of class `Box` such that includes both arcs and lines?

### Note:

Until now:

- I've (unsuccessfully) tried including an override of the function `void draw_lines()`: as a result I get nothing on the screen. In addition, if class `Arc` is included as base class and its constructor initialized via the class `Box` constructor list, I get ambiguities in the `void draw_lines()` function.
- I've (unsuccessfully) tried passing a `Simple_window w*` object to the class `Box` and then use it to `attach()` `Arc` objects within the function `void draw_lines()`.
- Another idea is to define class `Arcs` that holds multiple `Arc` objects and to add them either in the body of the class `Box` constructor or in `void draw_line()`.

Additional dependencies are [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/Graphics/). The *FLTK* could be found [here](http://www.fltk.org/index.php).

Comment: here is a hint: composition over inheritance

Comment: @ratchet freak yes, I've tried `class Arc: public Ellipse, public Arc{...};`, and it is not working. I'm probably not taking into consideration some inheritance properties from the already existing facilities.

Comment: An arc is not an ellipse. A box (rectangle) is not a line. An arc is all points equidistant from a central point and contained in between a starting angle and an ending angle. A box (rectangle) contains a collection of four lines, which themselves can be calculated using two and only two points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a way to use/combine the existent facilities, thus using directly the *FLTK* library here is what I came with:

```
namespace Graph_lib{
class RoundedBox: public Shape{
public:
    RoundedBox(Point ul, Point dr);
    RoundedBox(Point ul, int w, int h);

    void draw_lines() const;
private:
    Point upperLeft;
    int width;
    int height;
    // roundedness of the box 
    // should be changed together with Arc center, major and minor axes
    int roundWidth;
    int roundHeight;
};
// Class member implementations
RoundedBox::RoundedBox(Point ul, Point dr)
    : upperLeft(ul), width(abs(ul.x - dr.x)), height(abs(ul.y - dr.y)), 
      roundWidth(abs(ul.x - dr.x) / 4), roundHeight(abs(ul.y - dr.y) / 4)  
{ add(ul); }

RoundedBox::RoundedBox(Point ul, int w, int h)
    : upperLeft(ul), width(w), height(h), roundWidth(w / 4), roundHeight(h / 4)  
{ add(ul); }

void RoundedBox::draw_lines() const{
    if(color().visibility()){ 
    // Arcs
    // upper left arc
    fl_arc(point(0).x , point(0).y, width/2, height/2, 90, 180);
    // upper right arc
    fl_arc(point(0).x + width/2, point(0).y, width/2, height/2, 0, 90);
    // down right arc
    fl_arc(point(0).x + width/2, point(0).y + height/2, width/2, height/2,
           270, 0); 
    // down left arc
    fl_arc(point(0).x, point(0).y + height/2, width/2, height/2, 180, 270); 
    // Lines
    // top horizontal
    fl_xyline(point(0).x + roundWidth, point(0).y,
              point(0).x + width - roundWidth);
    // right vertical
    fl_yxline(point(0).x + width, point(0).y + roundHeight,
              point(0).y + height - roundHeight);
    // bottom horizontal
    fl_xyline(point(0).x + roundWidth, point(0).y + height,
              point(0).x + width - roundWidth);
    // left vertical
    fl_yxline(point(0).x, point(0).y + roundHeight, 
              point(0).y + height - roundHeight);
    }
}

} // end of namespace Graph_lib
```

The execution looks like this:

```
#include "GUI.h"
#include "Simple_window.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Chapter13Exercise2Version2.h"
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

int main(){
 // window parameters
 int winWidth = 800;
 int winHeight = 600;
 Point center((x_max() - winWidth) / 2., (y_max() - winHeight) / 2.);
 Simple_window* sw = new Simple_window(center, winWidth, winHeight,
                                       "Chapter 13 Exercise 2");

 // rounded box parameters
 int width = 400;
 int height = 200;
 int xCoord = (sw->x_max() - width) / 2;
 int yCoord = (sw->y_max() - height) / 2;

try{
    Graph_lib::RoundedBox rb(Point(xCoord, yCoord), width, height);
    sw->attach(rb);

    sw->wait_for_button();
    delete sw;
}catch(exception& e){
    cerr << e.what() << endl;
    getchar();
}catch(...){
    cerr <<"Default exception!"<< endl;
    getchar();
}
return 0;
}
```

And the result is:

[image]

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].